# Java Charset problem on linux

Tags: java, character-encoding, file-encodings

problem: I have a string containing special characters which i convert to bytes and vice versa..the conversion works properly on windows but on linux the special character is not converted properly.the default charset on linux is UTF-8 as seen with Charset.defaultCharset.getdisplayName()

however if i run on linux with  option -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 it works properly..

how to make it work using the UTF-8 default charset and not setting the -D option in unix environment.

edit: i use jdk1.6.13

edit:code snippet
works with  cs = "ISO-8859-1"; or cs="UTF-8"; on win but not in linux

```
        String x = "½";
        System.out.println(x);
        byte[] ba = x.getBytes(Charset.forName(cs));
        for (byte b : ba) {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
        String y = new String(ba, Charset.forName(cs));
        System.out.println(y);
```

~regards
daed

Comment: can you please post your code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your characters are probably being corrupted by the compilation process and you're ending up with junk data in your class file.

> if i run on linux with option -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 it works properly..

[The "file.encoding" property is not required by the J2SE platform specification; it's an internal detail of Sun's implementations and should not be examined or modified by user code. It's also intended to be read-only; it's technically impossible to support the setting of this property to arbitrary values on the command line or at any other time during program execution.](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4163515)

In short, don't use -Dfile.encoding=...

```
    String x = "½";
```

Since U+00bd (½) will be represented by different values in different encodings:

```
windows-1252     BD
UTF-8            C2 BD
ISO-8859-1       BD
```

...you need to tell your compiler what encoding your source file is encoded as:

```
javac -encoding ISO-8859-1 Foo.java
```

Now we get to this one:

```
    System.out.println(x);
```

As a [PrintStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html), this will encode data to the system encoding prior to emitting the byte data. Like this:

```
 System.out.write(x.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
```

That may or may not work as you expect on [some platforms](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html) - the byte encoding must match the encoding the console is expecting for the characters to show up correctly.

Comment: many Thanks..i completely forgot about this aspect - javac -encoding ISO-8859-1..i will check this out and get back..

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is a bit vague. You mentioned that `-Dfile.encoding` solved your linux problem, but this is in fact only used to inform the Sun(!) JVM which encoding to use to manage filenames/pathnames at the local disk file system. And ... this does't fit in the problem description you literally gave: "converting chars to bytes and back to chars failed". I don't see what `-Dfile.encoding` has to do with this. There must be more into the story. How did you conclude that it failed? Did you read/write those characters from/into a pathname/filename or so? Or was you maybe printing to the stdout? Did the stdout **itself** use the proper encoding?

That said, why would you like to convert the chars forth and back to/from bytes? I don't see any useful business purposes for this.

(sorry, this didn't fit in a comment, but I will update this with the answer if you have given more info about the **actual functional requirement**).

**Update:** as per the comments: you basically just need to configure the stdout/cmd so that it uses the proper encoding to display those characters. In Windows you can do that with [`chcp`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chcp.mspx?mfr=true) command, but there's one major caveat: the standard fonts used in Windows cmd does not have the proper glyphs (the actual font pictures) for characters outside the ISO-8859 charsets. You can [hack the one or other in registry](http://www.google.com/search?q=HKLM%2FSoftware%2FMicrosoft%2FWindows+NT%2FCurrentVersion%2FConsole%2FTrueTypeFont) to add proper fonts. No wording about Linux as I don't do it extensively, but it look like that `-Dfile.encoding` is somehow the way to go. After all ... I think it's better to replace cmd with a crossplatform UI tool to display the characters the way you want, for example [Swing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing).

Comment: posted code snip
iam pretty much confused about this file.encoding

Comment: Okay.. How about the stdout? The thing where the `System.out.printXX()` goes to. Did it use the proper encoding? E.g. if in an IDE, this is configureable in its preferences, or if in command console, this is configureable in its preferences. I don't do linux extensively, but it look like that the `-Dfile.encoding` has somehow actually influence on stdout encoding in linux's JVM.

Comment: iam running it from the cmd prompt and printing it there.
Also i am copying the same class file compiled on windows on to linux and running it

Comment: Well, then you basically just need to configure the cmd so that it uses the proper encoding to *display* those characters. Just to test, try to write those chars into a file (not as file name! but as file content) using `OutputStreamWriter(file, encoding)` and you should see that the characters are properly written (as long as your file viewer recognizes/uses the proper encoding to display them ;) ).

Comment: can you tell what cfg is needed on cmd prompt?

Answer (score 1):

You should make the conversion explicitly:

```
byte[] byteArray = "abcd".getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" );
new String( byteArray, "ISO-8859-1" );
```

**EDIT:**

It seems that the problem is the encoding of your java file. If it works on windows, try compiling the source files on linux with `javac -encondig ISO-8859-1`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: or `new String(bytes, "iso-8859-1")` in this case, of course.

Comment: thx for responding ...i tried using UTF-8 exactly as above and on windows i still get correct results..but i dont do that on linux since  it uses by default UTF-8 but it is unable to decode..
it appears to me as if utf-8 is diff on windows and linux..??

Comment: UTF-8 is the same everywhere, could you please check the .java file encoding. Sometimes there are subtile bugs when moving files from one platform to the other.